# IntelliJ IDEA: Navigate to the next or previous identifier occurrence using the Alt+MouseWheel

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1, there was [this nice feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/03/intellij-idea-2018-1-code-analysis-better-debugger-partial-git-commits-android-studio-3-0-and-other-improvements/):

> *Ability to navigate to the next or previous identifier occurrence using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel down</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel up</kbd> shortcuts.*

But, now that I've updated to the version of 2018.2.2, the same mechanism doesn't work. Checking the "Keymap" settings revealed that no entries have assigned the aforementioned shortcuts.

Please help me find the respective entry for the feature in the "Keymap" settings in the newer version.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest 2018.3 EAP, the action is called: `Go to next highlighted element usage`.
By default, it is assigned to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>wheel down</kbd> / <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

---

In the v2018.2.2, the actions don't have any shortcuts assigned by default. To locate the entries in the *"Keymap" settings*, navigate to the `Main menu > Edit > Find`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. In the v2018.2.2, the actions don't have any shortcuts assigned by default. For the record, to locate the entries in the "Keymap" settings, navigate to the `Main menu > Edit > Find`.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with your tip to make it easier for readers to find it :-)